# Cannot resolve @fontawesome all / fontawesome-free

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, google-webfonts

I am using vue.js 2 - I add some mdi-icons in my App.vue this generate a new error in my project
When I was trying to serve my Project but I got the error as it given as below [image]

I apply also some commands on it but it not solved my error.
Can anyone help me to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply solve the error by uninstall the googlefonts then again reinstall the google fonts by using following command.In my case I am using yarn so I use

**yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free**

But in case of user that are using npm they should use following command

**npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free**

Also the following link is helpful google solve links for Npm and Yarn

: https://www.google.com/search?q=font%20awesome%20add%20by%20yaRN&oq=font%20awesome%20add%20by%20yaRN&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160.11903j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: `npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` is enough actually.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using yarn then put this command

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

**or**

If you are using npm then put this command

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and add
`@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';` this in *app.scss* file

or add `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';` in app.js file

Comment: It says 'yarn add' twice

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, just resolved

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to have the `.css` extension, otherwise the import will fail.

As a reminder:

Install `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` (with npm or yarn depending on what package manager your project uses).

Then in your main.js you can just import `all.css` as per the example below

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

This will allow you to use the `fa` classes in regular HTML tags.
I also recommend taking a look at the Vue supported library for FontAwesome here if you want to have more granularity with your imports.
https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me, I Downgraded @fortawesome/fontawesome-free version to ^5.15.4 in the package.json